# How do I know if I am using my resistance cord in the right way?

Tags: strength, strength-training, exercise-technique, crossfit, resistance-cord

I have a new set of [Resistance cord](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008L61G0I) that I bought.
I am exercising regularly with it, but then how do I know if I am using it in the correct way?

Let us say that I am doing the [squat](http://www.google.co.in/imgres?imgurl=http://blog.gaiam.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/12/chris06_00143.jpg&imgrefurl=http://blog.gaiam.com/bottoms-up-4-exercises-to-lift-firm-your-glutes/&h=576&w=576&sz=109&tbnid=64Z3YZ2XeRV5ZM%3a&tbnh=111&tbnw=111&zoom=1&usg=__L8MLkcgmE0YEmdb26K93xffB1UI=&docid=K4G8DCWuCLO7kM&sa=X&ei=BUobUt2oD8SPrQedloCYCg&ved=0CC8Q9QEwAA&dur=9987) with it.

I am not sure if I am having an equal length of the cord on each side (from my hand to feet).
If they are not of equal length on both sides, does that mean that I am exercising wrongly and thereby building uneven muscles on each side?
If so, then how do I hold even lengths on each side?

Comment: Sorry if I have asked too many questions in one go. Can break them up into different questions, if suggested.

Comment: Just don't use tags as prefix for question, but as tags in the tags section. The amount of questions seems OK, as they are all closely related.

Comment: You could try folding the band in half and mark midline with a piece of tape.  Then you can step equally on either side of the tape.  I've never had a problem keeping it even, so that is my best suggestion.

Comment: @BackInShapeBuddy mid point is not a problem. I am talking about using the rope for a squat kind of exercise where we have to have equal lengths of ropes on each side after stepping two feet.

Answer (score 1):

I have been working out with rubber bands for 3 years now(after 7 with weights). You should always pay attention to the distribution of the length so that it is equal indeed. Otherwise it will(how you suggested) work both sides unevenly.

There isn't much of a science behind that. A mirror in front of you will make things a lot easier but you can do it without one too. Grab the band(s) and step in the middle. If you feel the band is longer on one of the sides just make a step in that direction and even the distance.

P.S. Just a side hint - rubberbands will never replace weights. They work your body differently and if you are aiming to gain muscle it will be very hard. If you are aiming for that but don't want to use weights then you should consider throwing body weight exercising in your workouts as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should watch a few youtube videos on how to use resistance cords. I find [Max Wettstein](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wzyCtzAF8F0) has some pretty good ones.

As for not having equal lengths of band whilst standing on the band, I don't think you should worry too much about that. Unless it's obvious you have too much on one side than the other, re-adjust your hands and continue with your workout.

The only advise with resistance bands that I would give is to start off light and work on perfect form. Vary your exercises also, the video I listed should help.

Comment: I edited your post, feel free to edit again or revert the changes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have watched a lot of videos. None of them I found that tells us about holding the band in equal lengths. My point is they don't even talk about it. I find it really difficult to find a mid range while stepping both my legs on it.

Comment: @Freakyuser Just to try and help you out a little more. I lay the resistance band flat on the floor then stand on a section (generally around the middle). Then you squat down and grab hold of the part of the band that's resting between your feet. It doesn't matter if there are different lengths on the outside of your feet. Does that make sense?

Comment: +1 for the comment. That is some lateral thinking, good. I hope I can think laterally like that for all issues in my life.